# AppBarLayout collapses when scrolling down

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using AppBarLayout in CoordinatorLayout wiht RecyclerView to have a parallax like effect. 
For the most part it behaves as it should, but on ocasion when scrolling down, the AppBarLayout would collapse as if it was being scrolled up.
Problem is I can't reliably reproduce the bug to figure out why that's going on. 
Here is my XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white_background">

    ​<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        ​
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            ​
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutTop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewImage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewBuild"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white_background"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="smartfactory.ch.frink.widgets.PatchedScrollingViewBehavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewNavigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="smartfactory.ch.frink.widgets.PatchedScrollingViewBehavior"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here's the video showing the [bug](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5m8v79a6dl40kzn/Bug.mov?dl=0) (3rd drag, at roughly 10 second)

**My question:** Has anyone else encountered this bug and found a way how to fix it?

**EDIT:**

After a lot of digging, it seems that there was an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=177729) that was fixed with the v23.1, however the above example was compiled with the v23.1, and the bug still persists, so hoping someone will see this and either tell me what I'm doing wrong or hopefully re-open the ticket.